# How to post HEAD request with HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, htmlunit

How can I use existing WebClient to post a custom HEAD request? I.e. there is no form on the page, I want to set request properties manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`WebClient#getPage()`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#getPage%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequestSettings%29) where you pass the [`WebRequestSettings`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebRequestSettings.html) in which you can [construct](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebRequestSettings.html#WebRequestSettings%28java.net.URL,%20com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod%29) with a [`HttpMethod`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HttpMethod.html) of [`HEAD`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/HttpMethod.html#HEAD).

Thus, basically:

```
Page page = webClient.getPage(new WebRequestSettings(new URL("http://stackoverflow.com"), HttpMethod.HEAD));
```